# Razor MVC calling Action from JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to call an Action from javascript with Ajax but when i publish the site the request returns me a 302 error

[image]

this is the javascript call

```
  $("#buyButton").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/TessileCart/Buy?offerType=" + '@ViewBag.offerType' + "&requestPath=" + '@ViewBag.requestPath' + "&currency=" + currentCurrency,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: ({
            }),
            error: function (data) {
            },
            success: function (data) {
                window.location = '/'
            }
        });
    });
```

and this is the Action server side

```
  public ActionResult Buy(string offerType, string requestPath, string currency)
    {
        try
        {
            decimal codStore = Convert.ToDecimal(HttpContext.Session[Global.CodStore]);
            string userName = HttpContext.Session[Global.UserName].ToString();
          
            cartRep.CheckOut(codStore, userName, System.Web.HttpContext.Current, currency);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { offerType = offerType });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Global.log.WriteLog(this.GetType().Name, "Buy", "", ex, Session[Global.UserName].ToString());
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Cart", new { offerType = offerType, requestPath = requestPath, error = Global.ErrorMex });
        }
    }
```

can someone explain me how to resolve?

Thanks,
Federico

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a post method, but using the get method way.

the url should stop until /buy

```
url: "/TessileCart/Buy",
```

before that build the post parameter, before the $.ajax call:

```
let senddata = {
  offerType: @ViewBag.offerType,
  requestPath: @ViewBag.requestType,
  currency: currentCurrency
}
```

the rest of parameter, send it as json as input to data

```
data: JSON.stringify(senddata),
```

and last decorated your action with HttpPost

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Buy(...)
```